# Change product name macro in iOS XCode project

Tags: ios, xcode

I built my iPhone code atop [Apple's sample project](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#samplecode/LazyTableImages/Introduction/Intro.html). It names the app "LazyTable" when placed on the home screen on iPhone. I would like to change this name. If I go to info.plist and manually type in a new name into the `Bundle display name` key, it works. But I don't want to hardcode because the `PRODUCT_NAME` is used in many places.

**Info.plist**

[image: info plist]

So I go into Project > Edit Project Settings to change the macro. I close the window, clean, and rebuild. The app name is still stuck with "LazyTable"! How do I make this change to the macro take effect?

**Project Info**

[image: project info]

Answer (score 5):

The approach you are using is correct. However, remember that each target can have their own settings that will override the project settings. Make sure the target does not override PRODUCT_NAME.

To do this, select the project in the Xcode project browser, then select the target. Each target has it's own build settings. Change the PRODUCT_NAME just as you would when editing the project build settings.

Comment: Can you provide steps on how to make sure `the target does not override PRODUCT_NAME`? I am totally clueless on IDEs.

Comment: Updated with more concise information on how to change the target build settings.

Comment: Experience by at least one person (Chris Fox) indicated that you might want to at least backup your data before trying this.

Comment: I don't see why. You are only changing a plist file.

Comment: Make that, experience by at least two people. Yes, make a backup copy of your app's whole Xcode directory before you mess with project and target names.