# How to change the product name in XCode 4.5?

Tags: ios, xcode

I have a workspace that contains a library and a project A, I wanted to create a project B which is the same as A except with a few small tweaks. So I copied the entire set of source files for A and make a copy, renamed them to B, then added the B project o the workspace.

I've created a new scheme for B but when I build and run the app has A's name.

I was looking at this past question
[Change product name macro in iOS XCode project](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7016788/change-product-name-macro-in-ios-xcode-project)

but I cannot find a Product Name row in the Packaging setting when using XCode 4.5.2

Comment: Check this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12848712/changed-project-name-in-xcode-causing-naming-error

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Click on the name of the project (the root node) in the sidebar once to select it. Then click it a second time to edit it.

[image]

When you press return to save, it will bring up a confirmation dialog that will show you the changes that'll be made.

You may need to update your developer credentials to support the new app.

Edited to add:

This should be a caveat at the end of every Xcode-related question: Restart Xcode. It fixes crazy-making problems. :-)

Comment: Thanks. However I've done that, and the project, target, info.plist etc. all have the new name of B. But when I run the target the app is getting installed with the name A (I've checked I'm building the correct scheme for B). That's why I was looking at that previous posting so that I could check what XCode thinks the name is (in the packaging section.)

Comment: Fixed it - not for the first time I've often found the solution to issues of things not updating within XCode when something has changed is just to simply exit and then relaunch XCode. And sure enough, an exit and relaunch solved this issue too.

Comment: That's happened to me way more often than I care to recount. :-)